# How to implement full-text search in a left join situation in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, left-join

I am trying to implement a full-text search in a left-join situation. I understand that I can't use the *indexed view* method since I'm using a left join - so I'm trying to figure out how this is typically implemented, since I can't be the first developer to run into this.

In this particular case, I'm trying to search the table `Inventory` and the search needs to include `Name`, `Description`, and `Vendor Name` (which is in another table).

The only thing I can think of is to create a new column on the table I'm searching, and keep it populated with the aggregate of the search terms I'll need - that seems like a last-resort solution, though.

Anyone have any insight on this? I'm pretty new to this full-text searching thing, so I might be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Limit both tables based on your full text search criteria and then join them.

Comment: That makes sense. I was hoping for a view or something I could apply a single search clause to (for simplicity sake), but I can work with this.

Comment: That's a bit different though because each table needs to match all terms, so if there were 2 search terms and one was the name of the project and the other the name of the vendor, it wouldn't work.